# gmail: how to customize title for my emails?

Tags: email, gmail

Recently I booked reservation in one hotel and received email with confirmation.

The surprise was to see in my gmail inbox special 'button' in the email record (see screenshot, "Modify reservation" button).

I believe that are some options for email which gmail handles in special way.

How to customize email to display such headers?

Thank you very much for any help!

[image]

Comment: I can't tell you for sure, but looking at the email in raw format (option "Show original") might give you some ideas. It could be a special header or something like that.

Comment: Good idea to try, unfortunately, that's gone... and now I cann't debug :( Maybe I should do another reservation to try :)

Comment: I also discovered gmail [Inbox Actions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/actions/actions-overview), which sound like what you were trying to find out.

Comment: Looks like that is the case. Please re-post it as answer so I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google have developed something called [Actions in the Inbox](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/actions/actions-overview) for Gmail, which seem to be what you were trying to find out. From the link page above:

> **Actions** enable users to interact with your product or service right inside Gmail.
>
> For instance, when a user receives an invitation to an event, she may be presented the option to RSVP interactively to the event from right inside the invitation. When she receives a notification that a magazine subscription is about to expire, she may be presented the option to renew it right from the notification.

Actions can be declared in two ways:

- as [In-App Actions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/actions/actions-overview#in-app_actions): **In-App Actions** are handled in-place, inside Gmail, without sending the user to any other website.
- or as [Go-To Actions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/actions/actions-overview#go-to_actions):  **Go-To Actions** can be used to provide a direct link to the page where the action can be performed.

The latter, *Go-To actions*, sounds like what you were looking for.